# Statically analyzing a Python module to find assignments

Tags: python, code-analysis, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to let my users write an `__init__.py` module like this:

```
'''
This is the simpack's docstring.

Bla bla bla.
'''

name = 'Name of the simpack'

tags = ['list', 'of', 'simpack-tags']

__version__ = '0.9.3'
```

And I want my program to be able to get all of these things: The docstring, the name, the tags and the version. But I want to do it without importing the module, because `__init__.py` might import the entire package which can be heavy. (I want to do this process for many heavy simpacks.)

We can assume that the user doesn't do anything computationally trickier then a simple literal assignment.

I heard that the `ast` module does things like this. But, I also want to be able to do this process on compiled files, e.g. `__init__.pyc` or `__init__.pyo`, and I don't know how to do this with the `ast` module.

Can the `ast` module do this on both source and compiled files? How is it done? Otherwise, is there a more fitting tool than `ast`?

Answer (score 2):

What you propose smells of difficulty and lack of robustness ... the `ast` component is likely to introduce version dependencies in your code.

Alternative: Instead of trying to analyse `thepackage/__init__.py[co]?`, have the users write a `thepackage/userconfig.py`. Then you can do `import thepackage.userconfig` without importing the whole contents of `thepackage`

Comment: I'd really like to avoid that. The `__init__.py[co]` should have a docstring anyway, I'd really not like to maintain two versions of it. (Nor to dynamically assign it from `userconfig.py` to `__init__.py`.)

Comment: @cool-RR: You say "I want my users to write ..." which indicates that this is under your control i.e. the contents of __init__.py are not predefined by a 3rd party. Why should/must it have a docstring?

Comment: I encourage a coding style where almost every object, and certainly every package, has a docstring.

Comment: @John Machin: `import thepackage.userconfig` triggers `thepackage/__init__.py`'s content import so it defeats the point of not importing the `thepackage` directly.

Comment: @cool-RR: Hand-written `sphinx`-generated docs might be more suitable as a package documentation than docstrings in `__init__.py`. Docstrings are good for an API-style docs; package docs should be more than that.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I prefer to stick with docstrings for this usage.

Comment: @cool-RR: I've not encountered yet an autodoc tool (epydoc, pydoctor) that generates nice API docs, so I prefer to read hand-written docs.

Comment: The docstrings are hand-written in ReST, and I display them on a GUI, I don't see what an autodoc tool has to do with this. I only take the docstring of the package, not of any classes or functions.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use 2 steps process:

- generate metadata in an easy-to-read format (such as *.egg-info files) during creation of source tarballs, eggs, etc. This step imports the `__init__.py` file. This step is triggered by a user action such as `setup.py sdist`
- read this metadata. This step doesn't import anything. It deals only with a simple text files

Comment: The simpacks are not necessarily top-level packages, they may be subpackages.

Comment: @cool-RR: It is upto you to specify from which packages the info should be extracted. It doesn't matter whether it is subpackage or not